# Target clicked element, not its parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function that targets the class .acf-field, finds the closest row and applies a class .active to it:

```
$(document).on('click', '.acf-field', function() {
            
    $('.acf-row').removeClass('active'); // removes .active from all rows
        
    $(this).closest('.acf-row').addClass('active'); 
});
```

My problem is that .acf-field is actually contained in an .acf-field.
So the function target the child element, adds the .active class to its closest row, then goes to the first parent, removes the class to all rows and adds a class to the closest row *of the parent*.
What i want is to target only the child .acf-field, not its parents.
PS: I do not have the possibility to target .acf-field better

Comment: If you have `.acf-row>.acf-field>.acf-field` then the `.closest(".acf-row")` of *both* will be the *same* acf-row.

Comment: Many questions on SO are because of a misunderstanding of what "closest()" does - it's not "nearest" it's "closest parent".   Can you include some HTML and indicate which elements you *think* should be active and which ones are actually being made active.

Comment: Add `event.stopPropagation()` or `return false` at the end of your handler, then it won't also fire for your parent.  https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: Or use a now-deleted comment and target acf-field better (despite saying you can't) :  `$(document).on('click', '.acf-field .acf-field',`  will only target the nested field, not the parent.

Comment: RE my first comment: unless you have `.acf-row > .acf-field > .acf-row > acf.field` (which a sample of your HTML would confirm)